# code running in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am having 3 tables case_details, codehead and case_staus. I am trying to fetch the values from database. Code mentioned below is running well in oracle 10 xe, but in oracle 11g 32 bit it is showing 0 rows...the code is

```
select a.case_id
      ,a.case_description
      ,a.case_contract_value
      ,b.sub_codehead
      ,c.case_status_name
  from case_details a
      ,codehead     b
      ,case_status  c
 where a.case_codehead = b.code_id
   and a.case_status = c.case_status_id
   and joint_directorate = 85
   and case_status < 2
 order by case_id;
```

I am unable to understand that well running code is not executing in oracle 11g...please help me out..

Comment: You may not have same data both 11G and 10XE

Comment: Nothing fancy in that select statement - I would check your data.

Comment: Select statements are pretty robust in Oracle (or any good DBMS).  Probably the rows you think are there are not.  Debug by removing conditions from `where` clause, by removing tables from the query etc. to see where you are going wrong.

Comment: there are specific rows for this. when I am running code with select * from case_details where joint_directorate=85; rows are getting fetched but when using above query it is showing 0 rows... I cant understand is there any specific syntax for 11g?

Comment: is there any driver problem? presently I am using ojdbc6 with tomcat 7.0.59. Submitting of the cases is working only fetching the data from different tables is not running..